# Was Roohdaar intended to be the replacement of Hamlet's father's ghost?

Tags: character, production, haider

In the film Haider, as I mentioned in [another question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55889/why-did-vishal-bhardwaj-avoid-supernatural-themes-in-haider-and-maqbool), supernatural elements were avoided in the film in comparison to Hamlet which it is based on.

But there was one character named Roohdaar, which I can't track in the original play. Even half of his name 'Rooh' means 'soul'.

So was he intended to be the  replacement of Hamlet's father's ghost? Or is he supposed to be some other character from the play which I missed to notice?

Comment: Yes he is... He inflicts similar effects on Haider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is meant to replace the fathers ghost character in adapted screen play of Hamlet. There is a clear dialogue reference in a Roohdar's entry scene to support this. In the scene where the man is refusing to enter his own house.

Arshia (Shraddha Kapoor) to Roohdar (Irfan Khan):

> "Aap Doctor hai kya" (Are you Doctor)?

Roohdar replies to Arshia:

> "Main Doctor ki rooh hoon" (I am soul of doctor).